# Magento 2 Module Install via Composer

Tags: magento2, extensions, installation, composer

I have created the Demo Module with only module.xml, registration.php and composer.json files in Bit Bucket Public Repository.

Please check my composer.json file

```
{
 "name": "hardikm219/demo",
 "description": "demo extension for Magento 2",
 "type": "magento2-module",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "license": "OSL-3.0",
 "authors": [
 {
   "name": "Hardik Makwana",
   "email": "hardikm.magentodeveloper@gmail.com",
   "role": "Developer"
 }
],
"autoload": {
 "files": [
   "registration.php"
 ],
  "psr-4": {
   "hardikm219\\Demo\\": ""
   }
  }
 }
```

I have submitted this package into the packagist.

**Composer URL:**

> composer require hardikm219/demo

I have run this command then I have got the following error:
[image]

But when i am running following command then it is installed successfully

> composer require hardikm219/demo:dev-master

can you please tell me how to install the extension without using the **dev-master** and can you please tell me why use the **dev-master** with the composer

Comment: Do you have a tag for your module? (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) If not. Build a tag. push it to your repo and try again.

Comment: Let me check with the inserting tag. Can you please tell me what is dev-master?

Comment: The branch of ur repo. Anything that is not a tag (i.e a branch) starts with dev-. e.g. dev-my_branch_name.

Comment: No, this solution is not worked